# Подсчёт суммы значений всех ячеек с определённым классом

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день.
Есть таблица в ней `<td class="sum">`, необходимо посчитать сумму всех этих ячеек.
Также подскажите как реализовать смену значения ячейки Цена `<td class="price">` в зависимости от значения введённого числа в поле `<input>`, к примеру до 50 = 88, от 50 до 100 = 70
Заранее спасибо.
    https://jsfiddle.net/Dumb/3xLrrdws/3/

Comment: Мне кажется это лучше делать не в html, а на стороне сервера. Если всётаки на js то у таблицы есть `rows`, а дальше ячейки через `nextSibling` можно найти.

Comment: Считать сумму значений ячеек  логичнее в браузере на js, да и искать ячейки особо не нужно: у нужных ячеек свой класс 'sum'. Я просто не знаю как посчитать на js все ячейки с определённым классом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```js
function calculateSum(inp,tr ) {
 if (inp.tagName === "INPUT") {
    tr.querySelector(".sum").textContent = tr.querySelector(".price").textContent * inp.value;
  }
}

function changePrice(inp, tr) {
   tr.querySelector(".price").textContent = parseInt(inp.value) <= 50 ? 88 : 70;
}

function total() {
  table = document.getElementById('table-price-box').getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    if(table[i].querySelector('.sum') && table[i].querySelector('.sum').textContent) {
      sum +=parseInt(table[i].querySelector('.sum').textContent);
    }
   
   
  }
  
  return sum;
}

document.getElementById("table-price-box").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  var inp = e.target;
  var tr = inp.parentElement.parentElement;
  changePrice(inp, tr);
  calculateSum(inp, tr);
  document.getElementById("total").textContent = total();
});
```

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table-price-box">
  <tr><td>Наименование<td>Классификатор<td>Свойства<td>Количество<td>Цена<td>Итого</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum"></tr>
</table>

<p>всего <span id="total">0</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Сумма:

```js
let arr = Array
          .from(document.querySelectorAll('.sum')) // собираем массив из нод с классом .sum
          .map((item) => {
            return item.innerHTML // трансформируем массив в массив содержащий уже не ноды, а их содержимое
          })
          .map(Number); // приводим к числовому типу

let total = arr.reduce((sum, item) => {
  return sum+item; // считаем сумму массива
});

console.log(total);
```

```html
<table id="table-price-box">
  <tr><td>Наименование<td>Классификатор<td>Свойства<td>Количество<td>Цена<td>Итого</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
<p>всего <span id="total"></span></p>
</table>
```

Замена значений в зависимости от ввода в `input[type=number]`:

```js
let arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]')).forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('change', handler.bind("", item));
});

function handler(el) {
  let itemValue = +el.value;

  if(itemValue < 50) {
    el.parentElement.nextSibling.innerHTML = 88;
  } else if (itemValue >= 50 && itemValue <100 ) {
    el.parentElement.nextSibling.innerHTML = 70;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table-price-box">
  <tr><td>Наименование<td>Классификатор<td>Свойства<td>Количество<td>Цена<td>Итого</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
  <tr><td>Корпус<td>ТТБ<td>Пластик<td><input type="number"><td class="price">88<td class="sum">11</tr>
<p>всего <span id="total"></span></p>
</table>
```